# Wordpress theme customization CSS

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i change Menu hover color in ecoshop wordpress theme. This theme buy form envato elements where i can find navbar css.

https://elements.envato.com/ecoshop-multipurpose-ecommerce-html5-template-DBTMXN

Please suggest me how to edit css of the Wordpress theme

Comment: it may help you, https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: Thanks Afrida Anzum Aesha :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put this css on admin dashboard -> appearance -> customize

```
header .navbar li a:before{
 background: YOUR_COLOR_CODE ;
}
```